# Break array into component arrays

Tags: python, arrays

This may be answered somewhere else, but I wasn't quite sure what to search.

I have an array (of unfixed size) such as:

```
arr=[(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)]
```

I want to turn this into 2 arrays for the purpose of plotting:

```
x_arr=[x1,x2,x3]
y_arr=[y1,y2,y3]
```

How can I go about doing this in python?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: @ScottHunter It has been less than 15 minutes, and this question is already the top SO result on DuckDuckGo. These terms aren't googleable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided they aren't too large (in which case you should definitely be using `numpy`), you can use `zip` with `*`:

```
>>> arr=[('x1','y1'),('x2','y2'),('x3','y3')]
>>> arr
[('x1', 'y1'), ('x2', 'y2'), ('x3', 'y3')]
>>> x_arr, y_arr = zip(*arr)
>>> x_arr
('x1', 'x2', 'x3')
>>> y_arr
('y1', 'y2', 'y3')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through lists in a compact way using this syntax

```
>>> x1, x2, x3 = 1, 2, 3, 
>>> y1, y2, y3 = 3, 2, 1
>>> arr=[(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)]
>>> x, y = [s[0] for s in arr], [s[1] for s in arr]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3]
>>> y
[3, 2, 1]
```